# SiteFinity based site not updating page title?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity

This one's got me stumped and it's driving me nuts.

I have a SiteFinity based site, using C# and ASP.NET.

In one of the master pages, I've added the line:

```
this.Page.Title = "Site Name: " + this.Page.Title;
```

This is *supposed* to concatenate those two strings into the title of the page. I've done this dozens of times...

...but for some reason, *in this site, and this site alone,* this doesn't work! I've tried Page_Load, Page_Init, Page_InitComplete...none of the events seem to update the title.

It's driving me nuts since this is such a simple bit of code, it's **supposed** to be really easy.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what *is* the page title? Are you sure the updated code is compiled and pushed?

Comment: Make sure none of the children pages overwrite the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this the old version of Sitefintiy (3.7 or earlier), or the latest (4.0+)?

If the latest, remember that Sitefinity is now a Web Application Project, meaning that as chase mentioned, the site needs to be compiled and uploaded for code changes to take.

hope this is helpful!